# Groovy Support in NetBeans IDE

Tags: netbeans, groovy

I was been reading Groovy for a month or so. And i fell in love with that language.
Recently i have installed Netbeans.(mainly for Groovy support) I have installed Groovy plug-in too, but still in NetBeans i can select New PRoject->Groovy->Grails application only. I want only support for Groovy. How to enable that? And there is no meaning in Creating a grails application without learning Groovy:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to select groovy project. You can create normal java project and then create groovy files in it.This [link](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/groovy-quickstart.html) should help.