# Wondering how to use Groovy 2.3 with Netbeans 8?

Tags: netbeans, groovy

I am disappointed when I installed Groovy 2.3 I discover that I can't use it with Netbeans 8.  Why?  Because the Netbeans Groovy support is fixed on the build-in Groovy 2.1.  This is in contrast with the way Netbeans supports Ruby, JRuby, Java... Where you can add a different platforms.

--[ ***update*** 2016-10-14 ]--

I went through this exercise for Netbeans 8.2.  The results are confused to say the least.  I think Netbeans would benefit by having a Tools menu item like the **Java platform** option to manage different Groovy platform(s). Or use GROOVY_HOME

On this PC the installed Groovy is:

- Groovy 2.4.7

  - one groovy Jar - groovy-all-2.4.7.jar
- Java 8 u102

This is quite strange.  The Groovy library in the Netbeans Libraries list was:

- Groovy 2.1.7

  - groovy-all

I actually removed this from the Library list and replaced it with the **groovy-all 2.4.7**.

I added this line to a Groovy main class ...

```
  println  "Groovy version: "+ GroovySystem.version;
  println  "Java version:   "+ System.getProperty("java.version");
```

The output:

```
 Groovy version: 2.1.3
 Java version:   1.8.0_102
```

I have been looking further.  The `Netbeans log` show me that the Groovy module loaded was:

```
  "Groovy 2.1.7"
  jar:nbinst://org.netbeans.modules.libs.groovy/modules/ext/groovy-all.jar!/
```

I checked that file, this JAR file reports its version:

```
 java -jar /opt/dev/netbeans/home/groovy/modules/ext/groovy-all.jar  -version
  Groovy Version: 2.4.5 JVM: 1.8.0_102 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

Ergo the label: "2.1.7" was out of date.

The thing to wonder about is *WHERE* does the groovy **2.1.3** come from when I run my Groovy from Netbeans?

--[ *end update* ]--

I scanned other Stackoverflow questions touching on this from earlier Netbeans versions.  The consensus I gathered was that you can "hack" at the way the bundled Groovy version is installed and it should work.  A Groovy release is more than just one JAR file so that doesn't seem like *enough* to me.  There ought therefore be more things to do for swapping-in a newer version of Groovy.  In addition, this procedure means that one cannot use two different Groovy profiles with Netbeans.

- [How to use Groovy 2.0 in netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626666/how-to-use-groovy-2-0-in-netbeans)
- [Groovy Support in NetBeans IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290392/groovy-support-in-netbeans-ide)
- [Groovy support in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560877/groovy-support-in-netbeans)

It can't be said that Netbeans could not support multiple versions of Groovy as it does for Ruby and for Java -- The IntelliJ IDEA does as does Eclipse.

I'm hoping someone comes with a suggestion for a complete swap-in to replace Groovy 2.1 with Groovy 2.3.

Alternatively has anyone seen a "language support" plugin similar to the Ruby platforms and Java platforms for language support, or a more general way to run scripts as external tools, Gradle or via Maven?  I definitely think it is a limited way to support scripting languages to just rely on a bundled-in single version.  It means a project will be stuck with 'old' language bugs and other issues just because of a lack of flexibility in an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

To use Groovy 2.4.3 in my projects, I followed the instructions in the *Groovy* tab at *Tools > Options > Miscellaneous*:

1. Download Groovy 2.4.3 binary distro from [groovy-lang.org](http://groovy-lang.org)
2. Create new **Groovy 2.4.3** class library in *Tools > Libraries*
3. Set library's Classpath jar to `groovy-2.4.3/embeddable/groovy-all-2.4.3.jar`

Comment: Sure I worked that out.  As I recall there were mixed results.  The library classpath is used at runtime, not sure if Netbeans itself uses the same path for Groovy files.  All in all the nicest comment I could offer is that I find the existing support to be lazy esp. compared to PHP, C or JRuby support.